# typescript Clone dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to be able to clone an object with dynamically define properties, is that possible?

What i have now.

```js
class User{
  name:string= ""
}
    var t = new User();
    var obj = {}
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
      get(){
        return t.name;
      },
      set(value: string){
        t.name= value;
        alert("name is set")
      },
       configurable : true
      });
    let s = Object.assign( Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)), obj) 
    // there should be and alert here but I get nothing.
    s.name ="alen"
```

When I reassign name, there should be an alert but I get nothing.

Is it possible to clone it with out doing a loop again and `define` its properties?

Comment: Interesting question  I have tried several solutions but with no luck. The only one working solution I found is [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#copying_accessors) from MDN. But again, this approach loops over all properties.

Comment: Yep, I will need to loop again throw all its properties, for Which I would like to skip.